# Is it possible to perform Authentication with Javascript,Knockout with Spring Security without using Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, knockout.js, spring-security

I am working on  an application that is built on KnockoutJS Frame-work with Spring Security for auto login.
But now i have to remove auto login and provide a login page which will authenticate the user.
However,i cannot use Spring MVC as it will disrupt the application architecture.
So,i was thinking if i can somehow intercept ajax request with a spring filter and fetch "Authorization" values for credentials ,then i will be able to perform authentication.
But i don't know how it can be possible without using Spring MVC.

Comment: Spring Security itself already takes care of the login just make sure you post the the correct URL with the correct parameters.

Comment: But what about login page?How am i suppose to create that?

Comment: Just create it in / with a technology you like.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security is independent of Spring MVC. You can use it with other technologies. In Spring MVC you have to configure the correct URLs you want to protect and the login page.

Here there is an example of using Spring Security without Spring MVC

http://www.swview.org/blog/using-spring-security-your-java-web-application